# IIS - re-route request to another node

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, iis-arr

I have deployed application on two windows servers(nodes) using IIS (7+). 
Under default web site I have configured two different services/application as follows.

On Node1 I want to stop Service1 & on node2 I want to stop Service2.

Hence, I have created app pool per service & stopped respective service.

Node1::

Service1 -> AppPool1 -> AppPool1 is stopped

Service2 -> AppPool2 -> AppPool2 is running

And vice versa for Node2.

Windows server nodes are configured in round robin load balancer. And accesssible over LB URL "https://LBDomainEntry/".
I do access services using below format:

- https://LBDomainEntry/Service1
- https://LBDomainEntry/Service2

Problem:
I am getting intermittent issue for web service. Sometimes reuest gets successful sometimes it fails.

Limitations:
I don't have control over LB. But I have control on windows servers.

Question:

1. How I can resolve this issue, is there any re-route option available
   to config in IIS to route it to another node ?
2. I came across ARR
   (Application request routing) feature, can I use it here & how ?

Comment: A well configured load balancing service should detect backend health status, and the reroute the traffic. "I don't have control over LB", then everything is impossible. I wonder why you mentioned ARR. What kind of load balancing is being used then if not yet ARR?

Comment: @Lex Li, unfortunately load balancer configurations are done by another team, hence I have limitations over it. I am newbie to ARR, mentioned as just a thought whether I can use it or not. "service should detect backend health status"-> my server is running (on both nodes) but one service from that server is down, my assumption is this is causing issue, as hits are routed per base LB URL."then everything is impossible" -> does this means there is no way to handle it from respective nodes/IIS ?

Comment: If down, there is no way on IIS to fix it. ARR won't help either as clearly another LB solution is used. Talk to them and raise your concerns. Any LB solution should have health check feature included.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li for your inputs. Any suggestions if I want to handle from LB side ? What type of rules should be used ?

Comment: @user2618875 first you need to find why the request gets failed. for now, you could stop the server which is not serving the request and continue with the working server. you need to troubleshoot the actual issue. you could refer this link and try to check the server health test:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj129384(v%3Dws.11)#32-configure-load-balancing-with-arr